# Trace the closest helicopter to the base station

Tags: prolog

```
heli_link_dis(h1,b1,800).   
heli_link_dis(h1,b3,1400).  
heli_link_dis(h1,b2,600).  
heli_link_dis(h1,b8,1200).  
heli_link_dis(h2,b4,400).  
heli_link_dis(h2,b3,2000).  
heli_link_dis(h2,b5,500).  
heli_link_dis(h3,b5,1000).  
heli_link_dis(h3,b6,400).
```

`heli_link_dis` = helicopter linked distance
`h1` mean the name of a helicopter
`b1` means the name of a base station
`800` is the distance between helicopter and the base station

I need the prolog code to trace the closest helicopter to a given base station

Comment: Show us what you've tried before you ask us to solve your homework. We'll be much happier to help you once you've made an honest effort. Did you read the document that told you how to ask questions?

Comment: Most epic question title. Ever.

Comment: Please follow [general](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) question [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extremely inefficient, yet minimalist, solution is:

```
nearest_heli(H, B, D) :-
  heli_link_dis(H, B, D),
  \+ (heli_link_dis(_, _, D1), D1 < D).
```